# oracle unable to access DB link

Tags: database, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a DB link to a remote oracle DB whose creation script is

```
Create Database Link "DB_LINK_NAME"
  CONNECT TO "SOURCE_SCHEMA" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'XXXXXX' USING 'DB00001';
```

But I try to access the DB link using

```
select * from dual@DB_LINK_NAME
```

I am getting error `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

I am successfully able to do `tnsping` to   `'DB00001'`

I tried both in sqldeveloper and Sqlplus

Comment: Add the details to `tnsnames.ora` file. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the details to local **`tnsnames.ora`** file.

For example,

```
DB00001 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER=DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME=service_name)
    )
  )
```

The cause is usually described as -

> A connection to a database or other service was requested using
>              a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not
>              be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods
>              configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier used was a
>              net service name then the net service name could not be found in a
>              naming method repository, or the repository could not be
>              located or reached.

Comment: Is TNSNAMES added as an option in NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH in SQLNET.ORA file?

Comment: yes. it is added. when I do tnsping i get Used parameter files:
D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora.   My Tnsnames.ora is also in  same directory

Comment: You need to add it to your *server* tnsnames.ora, *not* your client tnsnames.ora. Alternatively (if you don't have access to your server tnsnames.ora), you can add a direct connection string using EZConnect syntax.

Comment: And to add to @FrankSchmitt, make sure the directory path in SQLNET.ORA has the entry for EZCONNECT.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with you local tnsnames.ora. As a work around create the db link as follows:

```html
Create Database Link "DB_LINK_NAME"
  CONNECT TO "SOURCE_SCHEMA" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'XXXXXX' USING '(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER=DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME=service_name)
    )
  )';
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That's how I'd do it, as well - no need to edit the tnsnames.ora at all.

Comment: Frank, thanks for validating. This method has always worked for me too.